# Xcode build enables BITCODE for a framework only on Device but not on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, x86-64, i386, bitcode

I have `'Enable Bitcode' set to YES` in Build Settings, and have also tried setting  `'fembed-bitcode'` in 'Custom Compiler Flags'.
When I build the project with the 'Device' selected, and try the command from command line

```
otool -l /path-Containing-Release-iphoneos/Framework.a  | grep bitcode
```

I get the expected result as below

```
sectname __bitcode.
```

However with the same Build Settings, if I select any Simulator, eg: iPhone6S(10.2) instead of Device and build the project, and run the same command

```
 otool -l /path-Containing-Release-iphonesimulator/Framework.a  | grep bitcode
```

It doesn't find any bitcode inside.

Any reasons for this behavior ? Please note the Architecture and ValidArchitectures are untouched when building the projects with Device/Simulator selected